# Using foreach in Windows Phone 7 programming?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I made a game called Isola a while a go in C#, now I'd like to create another but in WP7. In C# "Windows form" developing you can use this foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (Button btn in this.Controls)

{item.enabled = true;}
```

How could I write this in WP7, since it doesn't like the Foreach loop and "Controls" does not exist???

Comment: In what way does it not like it? We need more information and an example of how you're trying to implement it. What language are you writing it in? There's a syntactical difference between VB AND C# which may cause you some issues if you're accidently trying to mix the two together.

Comment: Also, that's a very confusing way of formatting / indenting a loop.

Comment: For example:

Foreach (Button item in this.StackPanel1)  <-- Error

"Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' because 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' Does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: @Magnus Glannefors you are trying to iterate over an object which is not enumerable. Nothing wrong with the foreach, its like trying to iterate over an int.

Answer (score 3):

In SilverLight (XAML) the main Control (Page, Window, UserControl) is of type ContentControl.

Assuming you have a PanelControl (Grid, StackPanel, ..) as the immediate content of the root you could do something like:

```
foreach (var element in (this.Content as Panel).Children)
{
   if (element is Button) ...
}
```

This will find the Button in

```
<UserControl ... >
   <Grid>
      <Button ... />
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

but for Buttons on nested elements you will need a recursive method.

Comment: Magic trick: `foreach (var button in (this.Content as Panel).Children.OfType<Button>()) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

A `StackPanel` (the only specific you mention using) defines a [`Children` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) that probably does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted, my guess is you used WinForms. On WP7 the UI Framework is Silverlight, which is pretty different from Windows Forms. There is nothing wrong with your foreach, WP7 uses more or less .NET Framework 3.0, of course this supports the foreach statement. My guess is, the "problems" with your foreach is more a consequential errors.

Your Controls collection indeed doesn't exist anymore. Instead you have a `Children` collection BUT it greatly differs from the Controls collection, you might be used to. I suggest you read more into [Trees in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx) which is valid for Silverlight aswell. Also i would strongly advice not trying to change the behavior like this. You have much better and greater tools at hand using Silverlight, like [Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx).